# how to close all the open form in WPF

Tags: wpf

In my Application I have two buttons "open" and "close".

When I click open button window will be opened, when I click close button window will be closed.

When I click open button 3 times, 3 windows will be opened. I want to close all window when I click close button.

Here is my code  [Please don't try to Change the Thread because that is my requirement in my Application]

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Window ProgressWindow;
    Thread ProgressThread;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            ProgressWindow = new Window();
            ProgressWindow.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 50, 0);
            ProgressWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            ProgressWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            ProgressWindow.Height = 180;
            ProgressWindow.Width = 180;
            ProgressWindow.Content = "Hello WPF";
            ProgressWindow.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            ProgressWindow.Show();
            ProgressWindow.Closed += (sender2, e2) =>
            ProgressWindow.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        });
        ProgressThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        ProgressThread.Start();
    }

    private void Close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ProgressThread.IsAlive == true)
        {
            ProgressThread.Abort();
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to store references to created windows, your code can look like this:

```
Stack<Window> ProgressWindow=new Stack<Window>();
Thread ProgressThread;

private void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ProgressThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var window = new Window();
        window.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 50, 0);
        window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        window.Height = 180;
        window.Width = 180;
        window.Content = "Hello WPF";
        window.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        window.Show();
        window.Closed += (sender2, e2) =>
        window.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        ProgressWindow.Push(window);
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    });
    ProgressThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    ProgressThread.Start();
}

private void Close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    while (ProgressWindow.Count > 0)
    {
        ProgressWindow.Pop().Close();
    }
}
```

thread aborting is not recommended if it is "normal" workflow of your application, i.e. window wasn't closed because of some critical error

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend what you are doing and actually I don't really know if it works like this, but since you stated that it's your (strange) requirement to use threads like this, I will only comment on the actual problem:

You should save the threads in a List and then close all the threads from this list.

**Edit:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{ 
    Window ProgressWindow; 
    List<Thread> ProgressThreads = new List<Thread>();
    public MainWindow() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
    } 

    private void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        ProgressThreads.Add(new Thread(() => 
        { 
            ProgressWindow = new Window(); 
            ProgressWindow.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 50, 0); 
            ProgressWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal; 
            ProgressWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen; 
            ProgressWindow.Height = 180; 
            ProgressWindow.Width = 180; 
            ProgressWindow.Content = "Hello WPF"; 
            ProgressWindow.ShowInTaskbar = false; 
            ProgressWindow.Show(); 
            ProgressWindow.Closed += (sender2, e2) => 
            ProgressWindow.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown(); 
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run(); 
        })); 
        ProgressThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); 
        ProgressThread.Start(); 
    } 

    private void Close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        foreach(var ProgressThread in ProgressThreads)
        {
            if (ProgressThread.IsAlive == true) 
            { 
                ProgressThread.Abort(); 
            }
        }  
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to keep a record of all threads you have opened when you click "Open". Then in your "Close" method loop over that list closing each one.

Member variable:

```
List<Thread> allThreads = new List<Thread>();
```

Then in your open handler add:

```
allThreads.Add(ProgressThread);
```

Then your close handler becomes:

```
foreach (Thread thread in allThreads)
{
    if (thread.IsAlive)
    {
        thread.Abort();
    }
}
```

That what you are trying is unorthodox should go without saying.